# What is the difference between x++ and ++x

Tags: javascript, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incrementing in C++ -  When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x)

What is the difference between x++   and ++x ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incrementing in C++ -  When to use x++ or ++x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x) - even though the answer is for C++, it works exactly the same in JavaScript.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968371/understanding-incrementing

Comment: Wondering how someone should know that it works the same in Javascript and C++. The question was how these expressions work in Javascript. For me that is clearly not a duplicate question. Especially since as a beginner you just see language specific syntax rather than the abstract concept behind it.

Answer (score 23):

`x++` executes the statement and then increments the value.

`++x` increments the value and then executes the statement.

```
var x = 1;
var y = x++; // y = 1, x = 2
var z = ++x; // z = 3, x = 3
```

Answer (score 9):

`x++` returns x, then increments it.

`++x` increments x, then returns it.

Answer (score 8):

`++x` is higher in the order of operations than `x++`. `++x` happens prior to assignments, but `x++` happens after assignments.

For exmaple:

```
var x = 5;
var a = x++;
// now a == 5, x == 6
```

And:

```
var x = 5;
var a = ++x;
// now a == 6, x == 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write `y = ++x`, the `y` variable will be assigned after incrementing `x`.
If you write `y = x++`, the `y` variable will be assigned *before* incrementing `x`.

If `x` is `1`, the first one will set `y` to `2`; the second will set `y` to `1`.