# Javascript return var++

Tags: javascript, return, operator-precedence

So I'm wondering why

```
var x=5
function foo(){
  return x++
}
foo()
```

returns 5 and

```
var x=5
function foo(){
  return ++x
}
foo()
```

returns 6.

Is it because the precedence of the `++` operator excludes it from being executed before the return - ie. the precedence is `(return x)++`?  Or is there something tricky going on?

Comment: Nothing tricky. That's just the difference between ++x and x++.

Comment: Nothing tricky here. You have it right. Although the use of non-local variable `x` makes me cringe.

Comment: Look at it logically: x++ returns x before it is incremented. ++x increments x before returning it. Nothing tricky

Comment: @Floris: What's wrong with the non-local variable? How would this even work without it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: @Thilo - you could easily use `function foo(x) { return ++x; }` ; this would be more explicit. As it is, this modifies the variable `x` "silently` - there is nothing about the call to `foo` that warns you about this. It violates the concept of encapsulation. Makes my hair stand on end. More intuitive/pragmatic than syntactically profound. Just don't like it.

Comment: What would be the point of `function foo(x) { return ++x; }`? Since Javascript is pass-by-value, the increased `x` will just go out of scope. The current code looks like a very common pattern to capture a private counter. Like a `static` variable in C. And if that `x` is scoped in a way that unrelated code does not see it, this is a very strong form of encapsulation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between x++ and ++x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186027/what-is-the-difference-between-x-and-x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pre/post increment. It's just how the operators work. `++var` is *pre* increment which means the value is incremented before returning and `var++` is *post* increment, where the value is incremented after returning.

You can find more details about these semantics **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)**.

Comment: The pre-increment ++x increments the variable before the expression is evaluated.  The post-increment increments the variable after the expression is evaluated.  It is really two operations occuring in one expression, with different orderings.