# javascript function output problrm

Tags: javascript

The output of console.log(in1()) should be 11 but it's 10 why?

```js
function outer() {
  let i = 10;
  return function inner() {
    return i++;
  }
}

var in1 = outer();
console.log(in1());
```

Comment: `i++` says: when this line is over add `1` to `i`. For what you want, try `++i` instead, which is: do this now, then continue.

Comment: Also this: [Javascript return var++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262263/javascript-return-var)

Comment: And this could be the right duplicate: and this: [Why the value plus plus at last is 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316255/why-the-value-plus-plus-at-last-is-100/70316279#70316279)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment here:

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments and returns the value **before** incrementing.

Therefore, the postfix (that is, x++; postfix because it appears **after**) operator only gives the **existing** value before doing anything. That's why, when called, gives what exists, not what's the *result* of the addition.

Because of this, use the prefix operator instead, ++x, to get the value while still incrementing the variable.

The same applies to the decrement operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's because using `i++` returns `i` first, then adds `1` to `i`. If you call `in1()` the second time, you will see 11, 12 and so on.
Try using `++i` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When using the postfix syntax `i++` the value is returned before incrementing. Use the prefix syntax instead `++i`.