# I cannot find the logic error in this conditional statement. I don't exactly know where my logic is incorrect

Tags: java

I have the following statement...

```
personName[0] = n[y].getName().equals ("Penny") ? personName[0]++ : personName[0];
```

`personName[]` is an integer array. `getName` returns a string. Every time `getName` is equal `to "Penny,"` I want `personName[0]` to add one. How should I do this? When I run it, `personName[0]` does not add one and I don't know why.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Looks similar to the `i = i++;` error. Don't do this

Comment: I just made some edits to the question.

Comment: Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968420/1256113. The problem is that `personName[0]++` returns the value of `personName[0]` before incrementing, not after.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to abuse the conditional operator like this. A plain old if is vastly more readable and concise:

```
if (n[y].getName().equals ("Penny")) {
  personName[0]++;
}
```

If you *must* use a conditional operator, it would be clearer to use `+=`:

```
personName[0] += n[y].getName().equals ("Penny") ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to increment `personName[0]`, wouldn't be better to use just an `if`? Sometimes, conditional operator is to much for simple problems.

Comment: It helps the original asker if you can provide with your answer an example of supporting code. In this case, it would be more helpful if you could rework the conditional statement into a plain `if` statement, and explain why it is better than the original code sample provided.

Comment: @anothermh, thanks for the explanation! I'll do it next times.